# Get the Session ID and URL for the manually opened browser using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How do I get the `session id` and `command_executor._url` for a manually-opened browser in Windows using Python?

Using Selenium, I am able to get the `session id` of the browser initiated by the Selenium client but not for the manually-initiated browser.

Comment: a standard launch of the browser has no session ID.  (or at least not the one you are looking for... seems like you want the wire protocol session and there is none in a standard launch)